# how to call OnTextChanged in asp:TextBox when press any key

Tags: javascript, c#, ascx, aspx-user-control

I used an `asp:Textbox` as a search box on the `ascx` page. Now it works when I press enter after inputting my text. I want to change it to smart search. (when I press a key, the `OnTextChanged` should call to code behind the function without clicking anywhere or pressing enter key)
please help me to achieve this. Thank you

`<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server" placeholder="Search" AutoPostback="true" OnTextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged"  ></asp:TextBox>`

code behind in ascx page:

```
protected void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
     // searching
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the onkeyup event of the TextBox
to call JavaScript function which makes AJAX request to the server
to perform the search, to do so, add

> onkeyup="search()"

to your TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="search()"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then call the

> search()

function

Javascript:

```
function search() 
{
   var searchTerm = $('#<%=SearchBox.ClientID%>').val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "YourPage.aspx/SearchBox_TextChanged",
       data: "{searchTerm: '" + searchTerm + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
           // Handle success response
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           // Handle error response
       }
   });
 }
```

and finally perform your search in server side and return result:

C#:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SearchBox_TextChanged(string searchTerm)
{
   // Perform search and return result as a JSON object
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchResults);
}
```

Comment: This is a ascx page. not a aspx page. I can't do the expected functionality from calling to the main aspx page.is there any solution?

Comment: just make the AJAX request to the server directly in the user control (ascx) file. I mean replace "YourPage.aspx" with "YourControl.ascx"

Comment: if I add URL as 'YourControl.ascx/SearchBox_TextChanged', it gave me a 404 error. I think we can't make Ajax requests to user controllers directly. We can call to main aspx pages only. If I am wrong please correct me.